# How to filter elements starting with “A” from a particular column in csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm running this code but having no luck with selecting only the names beginning with "A". I would like to find a solution without using pandas library.

```
    import csv
    list_a = []

    with open('bl_printed_music_500.csv', newline = '', encoding = 'utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    
    for row in reader:
       if "A" in row["Composer"]:
       list_a.append(row["Composer"]) 

    print(list_a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can use `index` this way & filter your strings when 'A' is located at index 0

```
try:
   for row in reader:
       if row["Composer"].index('A') == 0:
           list_a.append(row["Composer"])
except ValueError as e:
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working. After running your code I get the answer - ValueError: substring not found

Comment: The problem is that if there is a list with hundreds of records(words), I'm not sure if selecting elements with their indices can work...

Comment: Correct, it should be wrapped with try-except. I've edited the code. it works on my machine, it should work on your machine too.

Comment: Amazing, it did work this time! Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question. How do I save the new output as csv file in python and open it in excel?

Comment: I'm happy it worked, I'll appreciate it if you upvote the answer. you can find how to do it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-save-list-to-csv/.